# What was the opinion of Hitler regarding pornography?

Tags: hitler, nazism

What was the opinion of Hitler regarding pornography?

Comment: What does your preliminary research indicate?  How can we help to clarify it?

Comment: Why are you asking this question? Do you have any reason to suppose that he *should* have had an opinion on this subject? Any reason to suppose that his opinion should be of historical significance? As it reads, this is not so different to asking what his favourite foods were, or whether he liked reading.

Comment: A documentary I once saw about the "[Entartente Kunst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_Art_Exhibition)" exhibition of 1937 had a section about how idealized Aryan nudes had become a significant portion  of Nazi art.

Comment: Nudes in art generally aren't pornography.

Comment: So tis question also needs a workable definition of pornography´. Alomng with prior research.

Comment: I ask this beacuse in this era the seventh are was born, particulary I am intersted in every government laws regarding this matter not just HItler. My english is no that good, sorry about that,  I need to practice. I like asking questions here is great fun. Buy I see that to find a good question in History is pretty difficult.

Comment: Check BBC history magazine.   They did an article on nudity in Nazi Germany.  The government approved of it

Comment: I voted to reopen. To me the question seems very clear.

Comment: Please vote for reopen, this is unfair, the question is correct and interesting. In our time there are many debates regarding pornography.

Comment: This is not a good site for "debates" - both pornography and Hitler seem to produce more debate than learning. I'm going to reluctantly vote to re-open; (a) Mr. Goldberg has persuaded me that the question is not what I feared; perhaps I closevoted too soon, and (b) there is an answer with upvotes.

Comment: @Feuergeist:The reason the question is closed is because it is "unclear," not because it is "incorrect" or "uninteresting." It is not "unfair: to close a badly worded question, no matter how relevant or (inherently) interesting. A one liner is usually a bad question on SE sites, almost by definition.

Comment: what part it is "unclear" it seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little research reveals that Nazi party policy on sexuality was somewhat contradictory. This is not surprising, the same thing happened in many fields. Hitler's views were presumably similar to those of the party that followed him.

The core of Nazi policy was the idea of "race" and its fundamental importance to *everything*. An individual's own body was not their own to do with as they wished, but belonged to the German race. Nichole Loroff's article on [Gender and Sexuality in Nazi Germany](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0ahUKEwihrKbMpZLSAhUMJcAKHVZyBeMQFghKMAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fejournals.library.ualberta.ca%2Findex.php%2Fconstellations%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F16286%2F13074&usg=AFQjCNFHm4neb7dThSovn9nqwjYISDDdJQ&sig2=KY9kvrtnb5rsijDHVhPM-w) seems reasonably thorough.

Like most authoritarian groups, the Nazis espoused social conservatism, and wanted people to stay in very traditional gender roles, with men dominating society. Motherhood was viewed as the most important activity for women, serving the race in an equivalence of the way men served it as soldiers. However, they didn't try to hide and deny sexuality, but to turn it to their ends in increasing the population.

So "artistic" female nudity was a major aspect of Nazi art, while unapproved art with sexual elements was automatically pornography and "degenerate art." Unmarried German girls were encouraged to have sex with men, which caused large numbers of pregnancies - seen as a good thing - and spread venereal diseases - covered up, or blamed on the women.

Overall, the policy was an incoherent mixture of social traditionalism and satisfying the desires of men at the expense of women. Katherine Burdekin's novel [Swastika Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika_Night) dealt with it rather effectively in 1937.

Answer (score 2):

In "Mein Kampf," Hitler railed that

> "The black-haired Jewish youth lies in wait for hours on end, satanically glaring at and spying on the unsuspicious girl whom he plans to seduce, adulterating her blood and removing her from the bosom of her own people. The Jew uses every possible means to undermine the racial foundations of a subjugated people." (Book 1 Chap 11)

Thinking as he did, Hitler probably believed that pornography was an instrument for leading German people, particularly women, "astray" (verfuhren).

Comment: Isn't this a bit too speculative?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: Hitler was also very aware of the value of propaganda and the media. If he believed that something was inherently "bad," he also believed that anything used to "propagate" it would also be bad.

Comment: Nevertheless, this is speculation.